# How can I add label names to the line labels?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, plotly-python, graph-visualization

I am working on visualization and basically, I have been able to create something as I want, However, I am having trouble with labeling the edges or (lines).
What I want to do is adding node names on nodes and adding label names on the line.
Any help would be super nice, I can't find the solution even after spent long hours on searching.

````
   A = list(result["antecedents"])
   B = list(result["consequent"])
   Edges= list(result["edges"])
   
   node_list = list(set(A+B))
   
   G = nx.Graph()
   
   for i in node_list:
        G.add_node(i)
   
   pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.5, iterations=50)
   
   for n, p in pos.items():
       G.nodes[n]['pos'] = p
   
   edge_trace = go.Scatter(
       x=[],
       y=[],
       line=dict(width=0.5,color='#888'),
       hoverinfo='none',
       mode='lines')
   
   for edge in G.edges():
       x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
       x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
       edge_trace['x'] += tuple([x0, x1, None])
       edge_trace['y'] += tuple([y0, y1, None])
   
   
   node_trace = go.Scatter(
       x=[],
       y=[],
       text=[],
       mode='markers',
       hoverinfo='text',
       marker=dict(
           showscale=True,
           colorscale='RdBu',
           reversescale=True,
           color=[],
           size=15,
           colorbar=dict(
               thickness=10,
               title='Node Connections',
               xanchor='left',
               titleside='right'
           ),
           line=dict(width=0)))
   
   for node in G.nodes():
       x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
       node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
       node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])
   
   node_adjacencies = []
   node_text = []
   for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
       node_adjacencies.append(len(adjacencies[1]))
       #node_text.append('# of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1])))
       node_text.append(adjacencies[0])
   
   node_trace.marker.color = node_adjacencies
   node_trace.text = node_text
   
   for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
       node_info = (adjacencies[0] ,' # of connections: ' ,str(len(adjacencies[1])))
       node_trace['text']+=tuple([node_info])
   
   fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
                layout=go.Layout(
                   title='<br>Association Rules connections',
                   titlefont=dict(size=16),
                   showlegend=False,
                   hovermode='closest',
                   margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                   annotations=[ dict(
                       text="",
                       showarrow=True,
                       xref="paper", yref="paper") ],
                   xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                   yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False)))
   
   iplot(fig)```

This is what I currently have:
[enter image description here][1]


But I want to see something like:

[enter image description here][2]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tleyG.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKlah.png

Basically, I would like to see node names and and label on lines. this is what I want to visualize:

antecedents          edges consequent
0          ?c         parent         ?a
1          ?c  <isMarriedTo>         ?b
2          ?b         parent         ?a

smth:  ?c ----- parent -----> ?a

Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a dataset, and the formatting of your question is a bit confusing. Nevertheless `fig.add_annotation` should be the way to go here. Regardless of what networking graph you're using, you should be able to retrieve x and y coordinates through `fig.data[0].x` and `fig.data[0].x`. Then you can build an accompanying annotation list for your nodes and/or lines like this:

```
nodeText = ['This', 'is', 'what', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'say.']*100
```

And then annotate whatever you'd like using this:

```
# zipped list of x and y coordinates
z = list(zip(fig.data[0].x, fig.data[0].y))

# some labels
nodeText = ['This', 'is', 'what', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'say.']*100

# annotate your figure
for i, e in enumerate(z):
    if e[0] is not None:
        fig.add_annotation(x=e[0],
                           y=e[1],
                           text = nodeText[i],
                           showarrow = False,
                           xshift = -25
                           
                          )
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
random.seed(123)
np.random.seed(123)

G = nx.random_geometric_graph(16, 0.125)

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        # colorscale options
        #'Greys' | 'YlGnBu' | 'Greens' | 'YlOrRd' | 'Bluered' | 'RdBu' |
        #'Reds' | 'Blues' | 'Picnic' | 'Rainbow' | 'Portland' | 'Jet' |
        #'Hot' | 'Blackbody' | 'Earth' | 'Electric' | 'Viridis' |
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line_width=2))

node_adjacencies = []
node_text = []
for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_adjacencies.append(len(adjacencies[1]))
    node_text.append('# of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1])))

node_trace.marker.color = node_adjacencies
node_trace.text = node_text

fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>Network graph made with Python',
                titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="Python code: <a href='https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/'> https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/</a>",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
                )

# zipped list of x and y coordinates
z = list(zip(fig.data[0].x, fig.data[0].y))

# some labels
nodeText = ['This', 'is', 'what', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'say.']*100

# annotate your figure
for i, e in enumerate(z):
    if e[0] is not None:
        fig.add_annotation(x=e[0],
                           y=e[1],
                           text = nodeText[i],
                           showarrow = False,
                           xshift = -25
                           
                          )
fig.show()
```

Comment: Vaov, that's terrific help! Thank you so much, really appreciate!

Comment: @volkan Happy to help! If you're happy with the solution, please consider my suggestion as the accepted answer. If a better suggestion turns up after a while, you can always accept that answer instead.

Comment: @volkan Thank you for accepting my answer. Now that you have more than 15 reputation points you also have the ppossibility to award upvotes to posts that you find useful.